# 1995 VW Eurovan OBD I to OBD II adapter

Tags: vw, obd-ii, obd-i

My 1995 Eurovan has a check engine light coming on. I have a standard OBD II reader but this vehicle requires a OBD I reader. I see they sell OBD I to OBD II adapters online but I have read that with these VW's I won't be able to pull codes even with the adapter. Can anyone tell me if the adapter will give me the ability to read the code it is throwing?

Comment: try your local auto store, they should be able to read the codes for you (usually for free)

Answer (score 1):

Usually on OBD 1 cars you can jump a pin and read the codes via a blinking light of some sort, refer to your van manual to find what pins to jump(with a paper clip) and then depending on the blinks the manual should have code read outs from that

Comment: The Bentley says - "Blink Method" - do not use, I have searched hi and low and cannot find instructions on what two wires to bridge?